# how to escape the whole string in python?

Tags: python

```
file=r'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
text=open(file,"r").read()
```

The file can be read, but at first I wrote `file` as:

```
file='D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
```

I can't read it as `text=open(file,"r").read()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\tdx\x0bipdoc\\szf10\xc0383.Txt'
```

What can I do in the case of not using `file=r'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'`?

Maybe I have to escape the whole string of `file` with some method?

The problem is: file was defined at the start, `file` is a variable containing a string now, I can only call it in the program, how can I repair it in the program.

- method 1: `file=r'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'`  can not be used.
- method 2: `file='D:\\tdx\\vipdoc\\szf10\\300383.Txt'` can not be used either.

When the program is already running, given `file` is a string variable, how can I repair it now?

Say `file` was not a string literal but was passed to my code from another part of the code, which I can not fix to use the correct format but still want to be able to use the filename.

Why can't I replace `'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'` with `'D:\\tdx\\vipdoc\\szf10\\300383.Txt' simply with`file.replace("\","\\")`?

```
>>> file="D:\tdx\vipdoc\shf10\300383.Txt"
>>> file.replace("\x5c","\x5c\x5c")  #can't work 
'D:\tdx\x0bipdoc\\\\shf10\xc0383.Txt'
```

I want to cut it into two parts ,failed.

```
>>> filename = 'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
>>> re.search('(.*?)(\d+\.Txt)',filename).group(1)
'D:\tdx\x0bipdoc\\szf10\xc0'
>>> re.search('(.*?)(\d+\.Txt)',filename).group(2)
'383.Txt'
```

With the help of Martijn Pieters ,i solved it adding  `'\300':r'\300'` in the mapping.

```
mapping = {'\a': r'\a', '\b': r'\b', '\f': r'\f', '\n': r'\n',
       '\r': r'\r', '\t': r'\t', '\v': r'\v','\300':r'\300'}
filename = 'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
for char, escaped in mapping.items():
    filename = filename.replace(char, escaped)
```

Comment: shouldn't those be `\\ ` etc?

Comment: For sanity, just use forward slashes in every path name and let python figure out what your platform uses for the path separator.

Comment: Or use `os.path.join` wherever necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your 'broken' filename doesn't actually contain `\` characters, you cannot replace those characters either. You have a ASCII 9 TAB character, *not* the two separate characters `\` and `t`:

```
>>> len('\t')
1
>>> '\' in '\t'
False
```

You'd have to try and 'repair' the broken string; this is *not* going to be foolproof, but you can create a replacement table to handle the *common* escape sequences. For filenames, which generally don't handle carriage returns, tabs or formfeed characters *anyway*, that's perfectly feasible.

Python string literals only support a limited number of one-letter `\` escape sequences; see the [Python string literal documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral):

```
\a  ASCII Bell (BEL)     
\b  ASCII Backspace (BS)     
\f  ASCII Formfeed (FF)  
\n  ASCII Linefeed (LF)  
\r  ASCII Carriage Return (CR)   
\t  ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)   
\v  ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)
```

I've omitted the multi-character sequences as these tend to error out when defining the literal. Simply replace these characters with the escaped sequence:

```
mapping = {'\a': r'\a', '\b': r'\b', '\f': r'\f', '\n': r'\n',
           '\r': r'\r', '\t': r'\t', '\v': r'\v'}

for char, escaped in mapping.items():
    filename = filename.replace(char, escaped)
```

Alternatively, we could map these characters with the `'string_escape'` codec:

```
>>> '\t'.encode('string_escape')
'\\t'
```

You cannot apply this to the whole string as that would double up any properly escaped backslash however. Moreover, for many of the escape codes above, it'll use the `\xhh` escape sequence *instead*:

```
>>> '\a'.encode('string_escape')
'\\x07'
```

so this method isn't that suitable for your needs.

For characters encoded with `\xhh`, these are much *harder* to repair. Windows filesystems support Unicode codepoints just fine, for example. If you make the assumption than only ASCII codepoints are used then it becomes easier. You could use a regular expression to replace these with their 'escaped' version:

```
import re

filename = re.sub(r'[\x80-\xff]', lambda m: m.group().encode('string_escape'), filename)
```

This changes any byte outside of the ASCII range into a escape sequence:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[\x80-\xff]', lambda m: m.group().encode('string_escape'), '\xc0')
'\\xc0'
```

With a carefully chosen range of characters, the above could also be applied to all non-printable ASCII characters, and repair most such broken filenames with *one* expression, provided we first apply the above mapping to replace codes that are not handled correctly by `'string_escape'`:

```
def repair_filename(filename):
    mapping = {'\a': r'\a', '\b': r'\b', '\f': r'\f', '\v': r'\v'}
    for char, escaped in mapping.items():
        filename = filename.replace(char, escaped)
    filename = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', 
                      lambda m: m.group().encode('string_escape'),
                      filename)
    return filename
```

Demo on your sample input:

```
>>> def repair_filename(filename):
...     mapping = {'\a': r'\a', '\b': r'\b', '\f': r'\f', '\v': r'\v'}
...     for char, escaped in mapping.items():
...         filename = filename.replace(char, escaped)
...     filename = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', 
...                       lambda m: m.group().encode('string_escape'),
...                       filename)
...     return filename
... 
>>> filename = 'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
>>> repair_filename(filename)
'D:\\tdx\\vipdoc\\szf10\\xc0383.Txt'
```

This should fixe **most** such broken filenames for you. It won't repair `\x09` for example, because that's replaced by `\\t` as well.

It also cannot detect *octal* escape codes, nor repair them. Note that `\300` was repaired as `\xc0`. This would require trial and error runs, trying out all possible combinations, or making assumptions about the input. You could assume `\xhh` never occurs but `\ooo` does, for example.

In that case the expression becomes:

```
filename = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', lambda m: '\\{:o}'.format(ord(m.group())), filename)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def repair_filename(filename):
...     mapping = {'\a': r'\a', '\b': r'\b', '\f': r'\f', '\v': r'\v'}
...     for char, escaped in mapping.items():
...         filename = filename.replace(char, escaped)
...     filename = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', 
...                       lambda m: '\\{:o}'.format(ord(m.group())),
...                       filename)
...     return filename
... 
>>> repair_filename(filename)
'D:\\11dx\\vipdoc\\szf10\\300383.Txt'
```

What works and doesn't depends a great deal on what kind of filenames you were expecting. More can be done if you know that the final part of the filename always ends with a 6 digit number, for example.

Best, however, would be to avoid corrupting the filenames altogether, of course.

Comment: `D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt` was changed into `D:\\tdx\\vipdoc\\szf10\xc0383.Txt`,how to make it D:\\tdx\\vipdoc\\szf10\\300383.Txt`?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: yeah, addressed now.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: the octal escape code is not easy to recover, that'd require trying out all possible combinations and seeing if the file exists.

Comment: i want to cut it with regular expression,but i can't.

Comment: >>> filename = 'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
>>> re.search('(.*?)(\d+\.Txt)',filename).group(1)
'D:\tdx\x0bipdoc\\szf10\xc0'
>>> re.search('(.*?)(\d+\.Txt)',filename).group(2)
'383.Txt'

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: with the last revision, at least your sample filename is 'repaired'. You're still likely to run into problems for other filenames though.

Comment: >>> s="\300" >>> s '\xc0'  why `\300` was parsed into `\xc0`?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral); that is a 3-digit *octal* codepoint. 300 octal is 192 in decimal, C0 in hexadecimal.

Comment: This is overly complex. [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) is the proper way of dealing with windows filenames.

Comment: @whereswalden: But that requires you not to screw up the string literals first. `os.path.normpath()` will **not** fix up inadvisably applied escape sequences.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Right, as [this article](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/) describes, you should instead specify your paths using forward slashes, which will be corrected by `os.path.normpath()`.

Comment: @whereswalden: Backslashes are fine too, provided you double them, or use a `r''` raw string literal. You don't have to use `os.path.normpath()` either; Windows accepts paths with backward as well as forward slashes.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `''` instead of `r''` you need to manually escape each backslash in your string literal:

```
filename = 'D:\\tdx\\vipdoc\\szf10\\300383.Txt'
```

Using `r''` is simpler because it disables interpreting `\` as an escape character, and thus `\` itself doesn't have to be escaped when you just want it there as a literal slash.

Comment: Please also add that on Windows since forever you may also use forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't because for instance `'D:\tdx'`, the `\t` is interpreted as a tab character.  You however can try to convert the escaped chars into something that resembles the original string but that's way more work than writing that file name properly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you originally write it using the unescaped version, you will have some special characters in the filename. It will also be in the directory that the script originally ran in.

`\t` will come out as a tab character, \v as a vertical tab, \s is ok, and \300 as a high ascii character.

I suggest you run the following command in python:

```
import shutil
shutil.move('D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt',r'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt')
```

Make sure you run it in the same directory that the script originally ran in. this should place it where you expect, with the file name you expect.

From then on, you can use the correct version.

Comment: no ,you can't do it.filename='D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'
import shutil
shutil.move(filename,r'filename')

Comment: If you run the above commands exactly, that will rename the file to a valid filename; after that you can use `filename=r'D:\tdx\vipdoc\szf10\300383.Txt'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything complicated, Python has built-in tools for dealing with this sort of problem, in particular, `os.path.normpath`. See [this article](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/) for the implementation details.

Comment: >>> import os
>>> file="D:\tdx\vipdoc\shf10\300383.Txt"
>>> os.path.normpath(file)
'D:\tdx\x0bipdoc\\shf10\xc0383.Txt',you can't get it.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Did you read the article? You have to specify the filename with forward slashes: e.g. `file = os.path.normpath("D:/tdx/vipdoc/shf10/300383.Txt")`