# how to understand the complicated lambda expression in sub?

Tags: python

In my question ,[how to escape the whole string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820158/how-to-escape-the-whole-string-in-python).
Martijn Pieters give me a good method to solve it,but i do't know the complicated lambda expression,

- What is the meaning of

  ```
  lambda m: m.group().encode('string_escape')
  ```
- How to explain

  ```
  re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', lambda m: '\\{:o}'.format(ord(m.group())), filename)
  ```

Comment: Why don't you ask Martijn in a comment?

Comment: the post is so long and it is the new knowledge ,new post is better.

Comment: Have you looked up lambda in the python docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda expression in python is a kind of anonymous function.

```
func = lambda m: m.group().encode('string_escape')
```

Is the same thing as:

```
def func(m):
    return m.group().encode('string_escape')
```

So basically, the first lambda means :

> Call the `group` method of the passed argument, and run `encode('string_escape')` on it.

Let's have a look at the `re.sub` call. The regex catches all chars whose code is between `Ox00` (0 in decimal) and `Ox1f` (31) or between `0x7f` (127) and `0xff` (255). This matches all printable "standard" ASCII chars.

So to each of those, we apply the lambda passed to the call (the matched string will be passed as `m`):

```
lambda m: '\\{:o}'.format(ord(m.group()))
```

This is a python string `format` call returning a backslash `\\` followed by the octal representation `{:o}` of the first argument passed to `format`. This argument is the character code (`ord`) of the matched character (`m.group()`)